# Create a dataframe with a column that will include unique values of a column and unique column names of another dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
dummy<-structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), `#BISB` = c(2, 
6, 4, 0, 4, 6), `#BISC` = c(2, 6, 4, 0, 4, 6), `#BISD` = c(2, 
6, 4, 0, 4, 6), `#BISE` = c(2, 6, 4, 0, 4, 6), `#BISF` = c(2, 
6, 4, 0, 4, 6), `#BISG` = c(2, 6, 4, 0, 4, 6), `#BISH` = c(2, 
6, 4, 0, 4, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I would like to reshape it in a `nodes` dataframe. This `nodes` dataframe should contain one column named `id` with index numbers (`1,2,3`...) and the second column will be named `group` and it will contain all the unique values of the column `Name` and all the unique column names except from the column `Name` from the `dummy` dataframe like:

```
id group
1   1     A
2   2     B
3   3     C
4   4 #BISB
5   5 #BISC
6   6 #BISD
7   7 #BISE
8   8 #BISF
9   9 #BISG
10 10 #BISH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may create a tibble with `summarise` by taking the `unique` values of 'Name', concatenate (`c`) with the column names except the first and then create the 'id' as the sequence (`row_number()`)

```
library(dplyr)
dummy %>% 
  summarise(group = c(unique(Name), names(.)[-1])) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number(), .before = 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
      id group
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 A    
 2     2 B    
 3     3 C    
 4     4 #BISB
 5     5 #BISC
 6     6 #BISD
 7     7 #BISE
 8     8 #BISF
 9     9 #BISG
10    10 #BISH
```

---

Or more easily

```
out <- data.frame(group = c(unique(dummy$Name), names(dummy)[-1]))
out$id <- seq_len(nrow(out))
```